# wpf page navigation in view model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

in my view I have a button. The button has a Relay Command, which do some action. After this action it should navigate to an other site. How can I do this. How can I navigate to this site inside my viewModel? I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks for your help
holzleube

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more the "navigate to an other site" part? I don't get it. Are you using and embedded browser control or what?

Comment: I use the wpf site. In this site I have some xaml code. So I can navigate with <hyperlink NavigationUri="mySite.xaml"> and this navigation I want to do in my ViewModel

Comment: You still need to be clearer about that 'site', and use std names. WPF does not have sites. It has Pages, Windows and Frames.

Comment: +1 Good question because the mvvm viewmodell should not have any knowledge about any assoziated views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to that question may not be as straightforward as you'd like. I think everybody has a slightly different way of doing it, so this is just one way.
First off, we use the Prism/CAL library from Microsoft, which has this notion of "regions", which are named placeholder controls (i.e. ItemsControl, sort of). Then on all of our "pages", we take in an instance of a controller we make called a NavigationController, whose duty it is to swap out views. The NavigationController is full of methods like "GoToHome" which do things like: grab the Home ViewModel from dependency injection (or make a new instance, depending on your setup), clear out a certain region by obtaining it from the region manager, then load it with the new Home view model. Then we wire up the call in our "page"'s backing view model to call the controller.

So, in summary, it takes some plumbing. Once you've got the initial setup, it only takes a few minutes to add a new page, but there is no magical "link" because you have to know where you're going, where it loads, and how to obtain the backing viewmodel.

Comment: Ok I think the way with the controller is my way. I have some questions left. I use a Window with a Frame. In Frame my pages are shown. To navigate the sites I should give the controller my frame object. Than I can navigate. Is this right?  Where should I give the frame further? In constructor or OnStartup Event?

Comment: Well, to do it in true MVVM fashion, you do your best to distance yourself from actual UI elements. That's what regions help to do: they give a globally named object that acts as a placeholder. Then you don't pass around references to a UI element exactly, more just references to a placeholder that can change it's location and style within the app. So if you change from a Frame to Grid, you're not locked in. However, if you don't want to pull in the CAL/Prism libraries, I'd recommend making something similar: a statically referenced way to grab named UI controls. This limits dependencies.